# Probability at least one good unit is drawn

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A company produces a certain product, in which for each $10$ units produced, there are $7$ good units. If $5$ units are drawn, what is the probability that there is at least $1$ good unit?

My turn:

The number of ways to draw the good units is 
$$C^7_1 + C^7_2 + C^7_3 + C^7_4 + C^7_5$$
The total number of drawn the units is 
$$C^{10}_1 + C^{10}_2 + C^{10}_3 + C^{10}_4 + C^{10}_5$$
So the probability is $$\frac{C^7_1 + C^7_2 + C^7_3 + C^7_4 + C^7_5}{C^{10}_1 + C^{10}_2 + C^{10}_3 + C^{10}_4 + C^{10}_5}$$
Is the solution correct?

Comment: probability $= 1 - P(\text{all units are bad})$

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote.  I assuming you are drawing from  a large pool, so that the probability that a given draw is good is independent of all the other draws.  So, then, just compute the probability that all the draws are bad and subtract from $1$.

Comment: The phrase "in which for each $10$ units of the production there is $7$ units are good" means the probability that an individual unit is good is $0.7$.

Comment: Yes , it means so @F.Taussig

Comment: So , how can i compute the probability that all units are bas ? @ab123

Comment: Do you know about the concept of random variables and the binomial distribution? If you do, try that approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A company produces a certain product, in which for each ten units produced, there are seven good units.  If five units are drawn, what is the probability that there is at least one good unit?

If there are seven good units in each ten units produced, then the probability that an individual unit is good is $7/10$.  Under this interpretation, this is a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) problem.

The probability that exactly $k$ successes in $n$ trials, each of which has probability $p$ of being successful, is 
$$\Pr(X = k) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1 - p)^{n - k}$$
where $p^k$ is the probability of $k$ successes, $(1 - p)^{n - k}$ is the probability of $n - k$ failures, and $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of ways $k$ successes could occur in $n$ trials.

In this case, $n = 5$ and $p = 0.7$.  Therefore, the probability of at least one success is 
$$\Pr(X \geq 1) = \sum_{k = 1}^{5} \binom{5}{k}(0.7)^k(0.3)^{5 - k}$$
It is simpler to subtract the probability that all units are bad from $1$.
$$\Pr(X \geq 1) = 1 - \Pr(X = 0) = 1 - \binom{5}{0}(0.7)^0(0.3)^5 = 1 - 0.3^5$$